# Facebook Cronjob Login and query data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am just programming an application to retrieve data from Facebook every hour (/me/events).
Is there a way to login my user and query the data via cronjob?

Later still more data to be queried, also from friends...

Is there a way login automatically, and query data?

I'm coding in with the PHP SDK.

Thx.

Comment: [Yes, there is.. using the Facebook APIs](http://developers.facebook.com/)

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?
How can i let the Server do the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With
[fbcmd](http://fbcmd.dtompkins.com/)
or [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) to use the Graph API with PHP.